# passing game pointer to units (cyclical includes, python)

Tags: python, logic, program-entry-point

### edit: I'm asking for advice / correct structure for code

The current layout (which is probably wrong), is:

- `Game` stores `player`, `screen`, and `units`.
- `Game` handles top level logic, user input, etc
- `screen` and `player` are used entire-program-scope
- `units` list is modified (added+removed) in game

If I want access to `units` list, or `Game.spawn_foo()` or `Game.width`, how should I restructure my code?

1. So that units.py can have access to the `Game()` instance?

## Code: (updated)

#### game.py

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = # video
        self.player = Player()
        self.units = [Unit(), Unit()]

    def loop(self):            
        while True:
            self.screen.blit( self.player.sprite, self.player.location )
            for u in self.units:
                self.screen.blit( u.sprite, u.location )

    def spawn_foo(self):
        # tried to call from Unit() or Player()
        self.units.append( ...rand Unit()... )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.loop()
```

#### unit.py , uses func or methods

```
class Unit(object):
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.sprite = # image
        self.location = (0, 0)

    def teleport(self):
        # attempt to use game here
        x = game.width / 2, 
        y = game.height / 2
        self.location = (x, y)
```

Comment: You fail to explain why `Game` should be instantiating `Unit` in the first place.

Comment: Because Game normally has a list of Unit's. It updates their locations, detect collisions, and renders them.

Comment: My fridge has a lot of cans of soda. That doesn't mean that it should go to the supermarket and buy them.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason not to keep a reference to game within each unit - ie adding a line to `Unit.__init__(...)` like `self.game = game` and then using this in your teleport method.

The only reason I can think of is that you might be worried about creating cyclic references which won't be garbage collected, in which case you could look at the *weakref* package, although it might not be much of an issue in your example.